# How many bits of information are in a single character?

Tags: passwords, bit

So I have a question for homework in my secure programming and testing class. The question is considering Windows NT or UNIX shell account. 
"How many bits of information are possible in an eight-character password if any character can be used?"
So the way I see it there are 95 possible characters on a standard keyboard. but doesn't it depend on the encoding as to how many "bits of information" are in a single character? 
I'm not asking for the answer, I just need help understanding the bit-character part, and then I can figure out the math on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got your 95 from the range 0x21-0x7E (inclusive).  Let's call this number "nusable".  This is all the standard printable characters from ASCII.  It excludes spaces/tabs/crs, etc.  If "character" is truly a C char type (8 bits), then nusable is 95.  Some systems *do* allow embedded spaces in passwords, so be careful as this would up the number to 96, etc.

If "character" could be any 8 bit byte value, the range would be 0x00-0xFF and nusable would be 256.

So, the practical answer would be 95, assuming no other encoding.  If this were an intro C programming class, this is the probable answer.  But, after looking at the wording again, I think it means nusable is 256, regardless of the fact that you couldn't enter it via a keyboard.

From this point, take nusable and the number of allowed "characters" in a password, which is given as 8, and do the math ...

So, if you're restricted to ASCII and/or 8 bit, you can stop here.

UTF-8 and UTF-16 use "codepoints", which can have variable size when encoded into a string.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8  UTF-8 codepoints are in the range 0x000000-0x10FFFF (the maximum is 1,111,112), and when encoded can vary in size from 1-4 bytes.  Note that ASCII characters from above map directly to the UTF-8 codepoints 0x00-0x7F and are one byte in length.  This is by design.

So the question is:
Is "character" a C "char" type:

```
(1) (char password[8])
```

or is it a UTF-8 encoded string:

```
(2) (char password[n]) where "n" is large enough to contain 8 codepoints?
    The maximum would be n = 8 * 4
```

or restated in codepoints as:

```
(3) uint32_t password[8]
```

If "character" means codepoint, then finding nusable is similar to what you did for ASCII.  But, not all UTF-8 codepoints are usable.  Some are invalid.  Some are special escape codes.  Some are unassigned and reserved for future use (e.g. Klingonese, should we ever develop starships :-)).  Some are for special symbols like "long dash" (e.g. "--" or "---").

So, for a given encoding we need to figure out nusable.  Can they be any language (e.g. english, swahili, chinese, german all intermixed) or must you assume a given language restriction (e.g. german will have far fewer usable codepoints than chinese)?  Any restriction on codepoints for the weird stuff?

Windows uses wchar_t (16 bits) to implement variable length UTF-16 encoding.  It is different than UTF-8 in how things are encoded, but has a similar codepoint range.

If the physical storage size can vary to allow the 8 codepoints [case (2) or case (3) above], take nusable and do the math [just like ASCII above].

If the physical storage is fixed [case (1)], this gets ugly.  Also, it's not too probable for a class exercise.  We'd be trying to cram variable length UTF-8 encoded strings into a fixed length string area.  We'd need to get a count of all usable codepoints of length 1 (e.g. 95), length 2, ..., length 4 into a vector of length 5 (e.g. int lenlist[5]).  Then, calculating the final answer becomes a problem in shortest path, tree walk, whatever.  We'd need to enumerate all possible combinations of variable lengths.This would need to be done for possible combinations of lengths in all possible positions such that it doesn't exceed 8.  These are not the droids you're looking for ...